# Terminal Server Filling Up

Tags: windows-server-2003, thin-client

I've inherited a terminal server and have found one major problem, the user profiles are filling up the C drive, I have  3.9 gigs free but that is going fast. I have a D drive on this server with plenty of free space, is there a method to change were the profiles are stored and move the existing information?

Comment: Are you using Active Directory?

Comment: Yes we are using active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to redirect folders like the users desktop, and my documents folder to some other location by updating the local policy or creating a group policy..  Those 2 folders mostly use up the majority of the storage space.

You should also probably enforce a limit on the browser cache size.

You could write a script to loop through everyone's folders and delete junk from the temp folder at sometime when they aren't using the system.

It is a bit harsh, but you could enable disk quotes, and limit every user to some appropriate amount of storage space.

To correct the current issue you may need to use some tool to figure out who is using all the storage space, and if their usage of the space is appropriate.   If someone is using the server to store their collection of MP3s you may need to tell them they need to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

@Zoredache has it.  Use Group Policy to redirect those key folders as well as set a reasonable IE cache size.  In your situation I think you'll really want to turn on disk quota's (maybe not enforced at first), that way you can see who is using up space and prevent any run away space use.

It's slower but you could also keep the profiles out on the network somewhere else, have them load at login, and then delete at logoff.  This is good if you have 'shifts' of different users in and out throughout the day.

A neat little tool I love using for digging through disk use is "TreeSize".  Google for "Treesize Free".